# AngularJS directive - accessing parent attribute from templateUrl method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a control with nested items something like list of items.
Lets say:

list

- item 1
- item 2
- item n

inside the item directive I can set template url like this:

```
templateUrl: (tElement, tAttrs) ->
    tAttrs.template or '/item-template.html'
```

it works fine but I would like to store template url as parent's attribute to avoid setting template for each item. Obviously the template is the same for each item.

The scope isn't set on this stage yet. So I think the easiest way to implement it:

```
templateUrl: (tElement, tAttrs) ->
    tElement.parent().attr('template') or '/item-template.html'
```

but I'm not sure it's the best way...

So my question is - what is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at [Creating Directives that Communicate in the directive guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  You can do something similar but you can make the require be optional in the (child) item directives

Answer (score 0):

I'd tackle this with [includes in jade.](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#includes)

```
// index.jade
doctype html
html
  include includes/head
body
  h1 My Site
  p Welcome to my super lame site.
  include includes/foot
```

I like to keep markupy stuff out of code and what you're doing feels markupy.